# Can I make an Outlook 2010 rule that's triggered after an email is moved or copied to some other non-inbox folder?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, rules

I'd like to make a rule such that if an email is moved or copied into Folder1 (where Folder1 is not the Inbox) the action is triggered.  For example, if I move an email into Folder1 I might want it to be copied to Folder2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the option to stop processing rules - this way you can create a rule that when an email arrives in `Folder1` (because it is moved) it is copied to `Folder2`.

[image]

Comment: When I create the rule how do I specify the Folder1 part?  Not clear to me how I specify that criteria.

Comment: @Matt: Oh, there seems no option to trigger on a folder, you could temporarily tag them with categories instead. Or you could [do something like this](http://content.screencast.com/users/TomWij/folders/Jing/media/3b367784-850c-4680-bfbc-fd0166a8b6e1/2011-04-05_1714.png)?